# Is sleuth compatible with retrofit2

Tags: java, spring, retrofit2, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-square

Is **[spring-cloud-sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth)** compatible with **[retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)**?

I know sleuth works out of the box with a spring MVC RestTemplate but I can't find any resource online to know how I can make it works with retrofit2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, unfortunately. But we're open to receiving feature / pull request so don't hestitate to file one in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have move to feign it seems to works well with sleuth

Comment: Yup, we support Feign. Can we mark this as answered please?

Answer (score 2):

you can configure brave's Call.Factory with retrofit with an HttpTracing bean configured by Sleuth and an instance of OkHttp

```java
retrofitBuilder.callFactory(TracingCallFactory.create(httpTracing, okhttp))
```

https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/okhttp3/README.md#tracingcallfactory
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/63cf3e66c4b661170a34a396e9be8a2a01c0e57f/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L484

Answer (score 0):

The situation has changed since the previous answers were added. Support for Retrofit with both`OkHttpClient` and Spring `WebClient` is now available via [Spring Cloud Square](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-cloud-square). You can find the documentation [here](https://spring-projects-experimental.github.io/spring-cloud-square/docs/current/reference/html/index.html). Information about Sleuth support can be found [here](https://spring-projects-experimental.github.io/spring-cloud-square/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-sleuth-support).